# Generate name of array with a loop java

Tags: java, loops, arraylist

I want to generate a new name of each new array that are created.

I have a SellAbleItem class, with a constructor, which takes the following:

```
  SellAbleItems Vodka = new Brunch("Brunch", 199);
  SellAbleItems Brunch = new Brunch("Vodka", 99);
```

I have this array list

```
   ArrayList<SellAbleItems> order = new ArrayList<SellAbleItems>();
```

And I put these inside my order array list

```
   order.add(Vodka);
   order.add(Brunch);
```

So, my question goes on how to generate at new name for the order array list? I would like to have orders, to be called like order1, order2, order3 and so on. And at the end, able to print these names.

Comment: Use a `List<List<SellAbleItems>>`, or a `Map<String, List<SellAbleItems>>`. The advantage of the map is, that you can actually choose a name (which has to be unique)

Comment: But I don't know how many orders will be made. It could be 10 or 20.

Comment: Describe what you actually want. Avoid XY problem.

Comment: `Map` has a generic length. You can always add new elements

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables). (this is for Python, but tl;dr, use a data structur)

Comment: Objects don't have names. What is your outer problem?

Comment: Create a `Order` class that encapsulate the name and the list of items. In future, you can add more to this

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6729605/assigning-variables-with-dynamic-names-in-java). [Alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19336202/how-to-create-variables-dynamically-in-java). [Alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038215/how-would-i-define-an-infinite-number-of-variables-java).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know how many orders a user creates before you create your map but you will need to know when a user creates a new Order. Once you know that you can add a Map to hold your orders like this:

```
// Program initiates
Map<String, ArrayList<SellAbleItems>> orders = new HashMap<>();

// User places order 1
List<SellAbleItems> order1 = new ArrayList<>();
order1.put(Vodka);
order1.put(Brunch);
orders.put("order1", order1);

// Some time later user places order 2
List<SellAbleItems> order2 = new ArrayList<>();
order2.put(Foo);
order2.put(Bar);
orders.put("order2", order2);
```

You can then loop through the `Map` as described here: [Iterate through a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/iterate-through-a-hashmap)

A better abstraction would be to create an `Order` class that has a `List` to which you can `Add` your `SellAbleItem` and then you can keep a `List<Order>` instead but that would be a different question.

Comment: That could be. But when the user interacts with my system, i don't know how many orders that would be made. So I need some kind of for loop in order make unique names like order1, order2, order 3 and so on.

Comment: If he want to iterate through all the order could do orders.keySet() get all the keys and iterate through all the names with a loop?

Comment: @PeterHoldensgaard You don't need to know the amount of orders. Any time the user creates a new order you create a new List and add it to the map. You can use `orders.size()` to figure out how many orders you have and you can use that index to name your next entry.

Comment: @LewisJefferies yes, it is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/iterate-through-a-hashmap

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to give names, just add `new Brunch` directly

```
order.add(new Brunch("Brunch", 199));
order.add(new Brunch("Vodka", 99));
order.add(new Brunch("Whisky", 1199));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want go list all the keys, then this will work.

```
Map<String, ArrayList<SellAbleItems>> orders = new HashMap<>();
orders.put("orderA", order1);
orders.put("orderB", order2);

Set<String> keys = orders.keySet();
for(int i = 0; i < orders.size(); i++) {
  System.out.println(keys.toArray()[i]);
}
```

Prints:

```
orderA
orderB
```